# I am having trouble creating a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Hello I am trying to write a stored procedure, here is the details of it
First you define a stored procedure in database_4 named getNumbers. This procedure takes
department name as input, and returns the number of instructors and the number of students in the
department as outputs. In other words, getNumbers() has one input parameter and two output
parameters. Test this procedure in MySQL to make sure it functions properly. Next, your
application program asks the user to enter a department name, and the program should return the
number of instructors and the number of students in the department accordingly.

Here is the tables for it

| Table Name | Column |
| --- | --- |
| classroom | building, room number, capacity |
| department | dept_name, building, budget |
| course | course id, title, dept_name, credits |
| instructor | ID, name, dept_name, salary |
| section | course_id, sec_id, semester, year, building, room_number, time_slot_id |
| teaches | ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year |
| student | ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred |
| takes | ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade |
| advisor | s_ID, i_ID |
| time_slot | time_slot_id, day, start_hr, start_m |

Here is what I have for it so far

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getNumber(IN dept_name varchar(20), OUT ins_count INT, OUT student_count INT)
BEGIN
 SELECT @dept_name = dept_name, count(*)
   FROM instructor
   WHERE (select count(*) from student where student.dept_name = instructor.dept_name);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

here is the code that will call the stored procedure

```
public void findHeadCounts() throws SQLException
     {
          System.out.println("******** Query 6 ********");
         InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(System.in) ;
         BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(istream) ;

//         CallableStatement procedure = this.conn.prepareCall("{CALL getNumbers(?, ?, ?)}");
//         procedure.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
//         procedure.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
//         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         try {
             System.out.print("Please enter department name for query: ");
             String dept_name = bufRead.readLine();
             CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{CALL getNumber(?,?, ?)}");
             cStmt.setString(1, dept_name);
             cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
             cStmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
             cStmt.execute();
             int instructor_count = cStmt.getInt(2);
             int student_count = cStmt.getInt(3);

             if (instructor_count == 1)
                 System.out.println(dept_name + " Department has " + instructor_count + " instructor.");
             else
                 System.out.println(dept_name + " Department has " + instructor_count + " instructors.");

             if (student_count == 1)
                 System.out.println(dept_name + " Department has " + student_count + " student.");
             else
                 System.out.println(dept_name + " Department has " + student_count + " students.");
         }catch (IOException err) {
             System.out.println("Error reading line");
         }
     }
```

It isn't going too well, thank you!

Comment: We don't know what database_4  looks like - please add table definitions for student and instructor together with sample data and expected output (all as text)

Comment: oops sorry, added the tables/columns now, and almost all the tables reference each others ID's so they are pretty much with each other by the id